# UWP StorageFile file in use by another process errors

Tags: uwp, storagefile

The data for my app is stored in local JSON. I was originally storing it as an string app setting, but that doesn't offer enough space. So, I'm updating my app to read/write from a JSON file in local storage.

My app reads and writes the JSON at various times as a user interacts with my app and I'm getting this error a lot when reading or writing to the file:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another process.'

Here are the methods involved:

```
    private static async Task<StorageFile> GetOrCreateJsonFile()
    {
        bool test = File.Exists(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + @"\" + jsonFileName);

        if(test)
            return await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(jsonFileName);
        else
            return await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(jsonFileName);

    }


    private static async void StoreJsonFile(string json)
    {
        StorageFile jsonFile = await GetOrCreateJsonFile();
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(jsonFile, json);
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetJsonFile()
    {
        StorageFile jsonFile = await GetOrCreateJsonFile();
        return await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(jsonFile);
    }
```

Sometimes the error is on the `WriteTextAsync`, sometimes the `ReadTextAsync`. There doesn't seem to be a specific point where the error occurs, just seems to happen randomly. Please let me know if there's some other way to do this to avoid the errors.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in your `StoreJsonFile` method. It is marked as `async void`, which is a bad practice. When you call this method and it reaches the first IO-bound `async` call (in this case `FileIO.WriteTextAsync`), it will just end the execution and will not wait for the IO operation to finish. This is a problem, because the file may be in use (or it may not even be created yet) when you call the `GetJsonFile`. Furthermore - the write may not start when the `ReadTextAsync` has already started executing because the system ran that method first. That explains why you may see the exception in both methods.

The solution is quite simple - don't use `async void` and use `async Task` instead:

```
private static async Task StoreJsonFile(string json)
{
    StorageFile jsonFile = await GetOrCreateJsonFile();
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(jsonFile, json);
}
```

And when you call your methods, always remember to use `await` to ensure the execution will continue after the IO operation finishes so that there is not a risk of race conditions.